# Poco TimeStamps and Timespans

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I'm trying to use Poco time classes to calculate some timing in my program. I want to detect a time out in a thread.

I'm creating first a timespan denoting my timout time, a timestamp for when the thread was started, and a check for if the current timespan is larger than the timeout time, i.e.

```
Poco::Timestamp startTime;
Poco::Timespan timeOutTime(60*Poco::Timespan::SECONDS); // 60s timeout
```

I want to check for the timeout in a timer function:

```
bool Process::isTimedOut()
{
    Timestamp now;
    if((now - startTime) > timeOutTime)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, the check for timeout in the above if statement do not compile: saying illegal structure operation.

Any clues on how to use these poco classes?

Comment: You should paste your real code. You've got at least one typo (is it `startTime` vs `mStartTime`). And paste the real error message, including the line number.

Comment: Perhaps this would be easier with `<chrono>`?

Comment: Howard: I looked up chrono and it looks as a good candidate for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with `Poco::Timespan`:

```
bool isTimedOut()
{
    Poco::Timestamp now;
    Poco::Timespan timeElapsed(now - startTime);
    if( timeElapsed > timeOutTime)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Key was to create a new TimeSpan object  and use that for comparison. You would think that subtracting or adding two timestamps would give a timespan object as an result automatically, but not.